# Is there a "good" way to apply margin to whole app in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

currently i am working on a nuxt app using vuetify.
The app is required to be run on a small screen (1024x600), not having scrolling and to have margin of 24px around the whole app.

Currently i faked this margin with

```
html{
  transform: scale(0.953125, 0.92);
}
```

but didnt found a way to do so with just margins/paddings on html, body or main.

Becuase vuetify uses the [v-app](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/) component for positioning the `main` `content` and `header`, those layout components start to overlap each other when i apply margins to the body/html tags or the v-app component or the `v-overlay`  isnt positioned correctly.

Does anybody got an idea how to apply a propert margin around a vuetify app without crazy css rules scattered around several components/html tags?

Comment: This scale will not work if the resolution is bigger. Also, the easiest would be to inspect the DOM, find the class that brings some margins and override it.